# Robotium and Sherlock - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, exception, testing, android-actionbar, robotium

I've got problems with test in my project. I've got configured dependencies correctly but I can't run tests using Robotium. When my activity extends just Activity - everything is fine, when I add "extends SherlockActivity" then I got

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:238)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.calculator.Main (example project from Robotium www).
```

I have tried to run test in Intellij and Eclipse. Both IDE gave same results.

Edit: It's my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.calculator.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <instrumentation android:targetPackage="com.calculator" android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you compiled your class with correct dependencies but did not specify them at runtime. As both IntelliJ and Eclipse should use the same configuration for run like compile, the question is: how did you run the test?

Comment: In Intellij there is not a lot of options about run configuration. I've set it to start one class with test. I've added manifest above. Strange is that "TestMain extends Activity" works but "TestMain extends SherlockActivity" doesn't

Answer (score 0):

it is not problem with any editor you used.

here is general syntax to start any activity from adb shell:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

So, when you call any activity from robotium it must " extends Activity ".

and " extends SherlockActivity " is not work with robotium because of above syntax required Activity name only. So if you extends any other thing it will not work.

Note :

[1] first try to open your activity with syntax bellow

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.calculator/com.calculator.Main
```

here " Main " is activity in your package " com.calculator ".

[2] if this work for you then and then it will work for robotium.

i hope this concept will help you. thanks.

Comment: I can run my application using code above but I still don't know how it helps me. Could you describe point [2] more in detail ? How can I use this in Eclipse/Intellij ? 

When I want to run it manually it doesn't work (same error as above - NoClassDefFoundError). Code:
adb shell am instrument -w com.calculator.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

Comment: first try to execute " adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.calculator/com.calculator.Main" from command prompt. if it runs then go with robotium. because when you try start any activity with robotium code it follows "adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.calculator/com.calculator.Main" thing first.